# How to get names of the table attributes?

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key

I am working Sql Server 2005
My table name is Customer, the attributes are

Orderid
Customerid
Customeraddress

Wherein Customerid is the primary key and Orderid is the foreign key.

I want to know the 
primary key name, 
foreign key name and 
the table name where the foreign key exists as a primary key

Is there any query to retrieve those names using a table name?
Kindly please provide me the queries...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

--list all columns in BLAH table
select c.name 
from sys.columns c, sys.tables t
where c.object_id=t.object_id 
  and t.name='BLAH'